# sizeOf Struct and sizeOf Instance variable return different values

Tags: objective-c

I'm working with a C Api in Objective-C. This API needs to use some specific structures. 
I have some problems trying to figure out how to work with arrays of structure.

I show you something more with some code:

I have the class `Sprite` where I define the struct `Vertex`. 
Every instance of Sprite has its own array of Vertices.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  

typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
} Vertex;

@interface Sprite : NSObject{
    Vertex *_vertices;
}

//Getter setter methods 
-(void)setVertices:(Vertex*)vx;
-(Vertex*)vertices;
@end
```

In another class I use the Sprite class in this way:
I create a Vertex array and I assign this struct to one instance of Sprite:

```
Sprite *spr = [[Sprite alloc]init];

Vertex vertices2[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
    {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}},
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}}
};

spr.vertices = vertices2;
```

Now if I perform `sizeOf` directly on the `vertices2` struct I get the value `112` and  performing `sizeOf` on `spr.vertices` I get `4`. Why??? I mean this is the same struct with the same values.

My doubt is that I'm working with array[] and with pointer* in the wrong way...

How can I modify the Sprite class to use array of struct the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` computes the size of its argument at compile time. If you pass it a pointer, it will return the size of the pointer type (usually 4 or 8 bytes). Even if you pass it a dereferenced pointer, i.e. `sizeof(*spr.vertices)`, you will get the size of the `Vertex` type, not your particular instance.

If you need to know the size of the instance at runtime, put it (the size) in another ivar.

Comment: `sizeof` isn't always computed at compile time; for example, with variable length arrays.  This isn't one of those cases, though.

Answer (score 2):

`spr.vertices` is a pointer.  The `vertices2` is an actual array of your Vertex objects.  They are different data types.

Comment: Ok, so how can I add the array as instance variable for the class Sprite? I can't write 
 `@interface Sprite : NSObject{
     Vertex _vertices[];
 }`

Comment: If you know the size, you can specify it in your array declaration.  I.E. `Vertex _vertices[4]`.  If you have variable length arrays, then you will need to store a pointer to the vertices array and the length of the array and do sizeof(Vertex) * arrayLen